# Is it possible to detect if the callee forwards the call to a specific number?

Tags: sip, voip

I'm not super familiar with VOIP.. I've been doing some research but have had a difficult time finding an answer to this question.

What I need to do, is check to make sure a phone is being forwarded to a specific number. I'm trying to determine if there is a way to do this by placing a call to it.  Looking at [rfc 3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt), it seems the VIA header would contain the info I need if a forwarding phone just acts as a proxy, but it seems this is unlikely to work, judging from the line:

> Each proxy uses the Via header field to
>      determine where to send the response and removes its own address from
>      the top.

Is it possible to tell if a call was forwarded to a specific number, simply by placing a call to it and monitoring the headers? If so, could I simply download a VOIP app, and snoop the packets with WireShark? Or will I need to create my own VOIP client?

Comment: Hmm ... do you want to know if your destination (=callee SIP phone) is up and running, or do you want to know through what SIP hops (=SIP proxy) the SIP call was routed? Please update your description!

Comment: I want to know if the callee forwards the call to a specific number. Basically it's a business phone that should automatically forward to a cell phone at certain times, but in the past we've had trouble with it not. I'd like to be able to programmatically check that it's forwarded, but don't have access to the providers APIs.

Comment: Based on the RFC it seemed reasonable to assume that a forwarded phone acts as a proxy, which was why I talk about proxies in the question, but I didn't really see any concrete details on how it's implemented. If I could get the sip hops the call was routed through, I think that should probably be enough information to do what I need..

Comment: Check if you can use either the `Record-Route` header (http://www.tech-invite.com/fo-sip/tinv-fo-sip-dialog.html) or  the SIP `history-info` header (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4244 for details).

Comment: Thanks so much. The start of section 3 in RFC 4244 makes it sound like the `Record-Route` header wouldn't work for forwarded calls, but it does sound like `history-info` may be what I'm looking for.
This answers my question, so feel free to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SIP history-info header, see [rfc4244](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4244) for details.